# Is it possible to shorten singleton methods calls ?

Tags: swift, singleton, class-method

I'm trying to shorten the method calls on a singleton.

Would a class method calling an instance method on a singleton defeat the purpose of a singleton ?

```
class ClientClass{
    static let sharedInstance = ClientClass()
    private init() {}

    fileprivate func myMethod(){
        print("Hello")
    }
}

extension ClientClass{
    class func myMethod(){
        self.sharedInstance.myMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call it `shared` for succinctness (and also align with Swift 3's style). And yes, It doesn't make sense to declare static method just for the singleton

Comment: @CodeDifferent So if I understand correctly, it doesn't make sense to create a static method that calls an instance method for a singleton. Your advice is to shorten the static variable's name to `shared`, this way the method calls will be a bit shorter.